# I'm having an issue posting my app to heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, heroku, posting

So my issue is whenever I attempt to push my app to heroku it attempts to do so but then when the percentage section shows up it can never get past 70%. I have scanned the error message, ran npm run build which worked perfectly normally, scanned the previous messages and attempted every fix on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys which it keeps pointing me to. Besides the initial error at 70% there is also something that caught my eye at 40% so I will also post that here:

70% Error:

```
<s> [webpack.Progress] 70% building 402/402 modules 0 active 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-router@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress --display-error-details --color`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-router@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LhBS8/_logs/2021-11-29T16_19_55_351Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.LhBS8/_logs/2021-11-29T16_19_55_502Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

To give some context with this error, it almost seems like heroku is looking for a scss file in my navigation folder along with my navigation bar component, however I have never once had a scss file in that folder.

40% Error that didn't stop the upload process:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './navigation/navBar' in '/tmp/build_99a5894a/src/components'
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:925:10
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:401:22
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:130:21
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:224:22
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6877:13
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:214:25
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:213:14
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/UnsafeCachePlugin.js:44:7
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DescriptionFilePlugin.js:67:43
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:16:1)
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:285:5
    at eval (eval at create (/tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/DirectoryExistsPlugin.js:27:15
    at /tmp/build_99a5894a/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:85:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
resolve './navigation/navBar' in '/tmp/build_99a5894a/src/components'
  using description file: /tmp/build_99a5894a/package.json (relative path: ./src/components)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    using description file: /tmp/build_99a5894a/package.json (relative path: ./src/components/navigation/navBar)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /tmp/build_99a5894a/src/components/navigation/navBar doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /tmp/build_99a5894a/src/components/navigation/navBar.js doesn't exist
      .scss
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /tmp/build_99a5894a/src/components/navigation/navBar.scss doesn't exist
      as directory
        /tmp/build_99a5894a/src/components/navigation/navBar doesn't exist
```

Comment: You are able to do `npm run build` on your computer or it still give errors?

Comment: `npm run build` seems to work just fine

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue. Apparently in one of my files I had a capital B in a path import statement in which the actual file was all lowercase. I had no idea that one capital B could cause my entire program to fail. Check your spelling folks!